# How do I write messages when sending Outlook email using Python?

Tags: python, outlook

I want to write messages in Outlook using Python:

> Hi everyone,
>
> Please help follow up with the following opportunities:
> [Insert html table]
>
> Best,
> XXX

I have tried but the formatting looks off, e.g. the sentence "Please help follow up with the following opportunities" does not appear on a separate line

```
def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)

table = dummy.to_html()

Emailer('Hi everyone, \n\nPlease help follow up the following opportunities:'+table+'Best,\nXXX','PSE','XXX@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to use html syntax:

```
Emailer('Hi everyone, <br>Please help follow up the following opportunities:'+table+'Best,<br>XXX','PSE','XXX@gmail.com')
```